# ssh not honoring -i switch

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I have a bunch of keys in .ssh folder in my home. If I try to log into an ec2 instance using the below

```
ssh -2 -vvvv -i ~/.ec2/boogoo.pem ubuntu@ec2-54-225-36-186.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

I see this in the debug output:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: abhi@panini
```

I see a bunch of keys tried like this until the server bars the ssh attempt with the message

```
Too many authentication failures
```

Now, if I delete my .ssh folder, the first key that is tried after the ***"debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey"*** is the boogoo.pem key and I can log into the server.

I am confused as to why this behvaiour? Should not the -i switch make it clear to ssh client that the boogoo.pem is the key that it should try first instead of trying all the other keys present in .ssh folder?

Comment: Try with the full path, `/home/boogoo/.ec2/boogoo.pem` ?

Comment: Tried that too, does not make a difference.

Comment: Can you put the key in the .ssh directory?

Comment: Tried that too and also putting the whole thing in the config file and using the alias to ssh.

Comment: If you add the lines: `Host ec2-54-225-36-186.compute-1.amazonaws.com`  
`Hostname ec2-54-225-36-186.compute-1.amazonaws.com`  
`IdentityFile ~/.ec2/boogoo.pem`  to your /etc/ssh_config file ?

Comment: Tried the ssh config file too, does not make a difference.

Comment: That's just nuts..

Comment: I know, that is what is bothering me, not knowing what is happening is so frustrating.

Comment: Just a dumb thing to try, if you drop the .pem from the command line connection, just `-i ~/.ec2/boogoo` ?

Comment: Try running `unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK` before connecting?

Comment: Please paste full debug output after you executed your ssh command, it could be your pem didn't get load because of permission issue, but need the full log to be sure

Comment: Perhaps the permissions of the key are too loose? Can you confirm the permissions used for the key? Please send the output of ls -l ~/.ec2/boogoo.pem ls -ld ~/.ec2/

Answer (score 1):

Add `-o "IdentitiesOnly yes"` to the command line, or add `IdentitiesOnly yes` to the appropriate section in your `~/.ssh/config`.

By default `ssh` offers all keys from the default location in `~/.ssh` and all identities represented by the authentication agent to the remote system, and if you have too many keys there, the remote system can kick you out for too many failures. Enabling the `IdentitiesOnly` option specifies that only explicitly configured identities should be offered, and this fixes the problem.

See also [this answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/187790/58777).